# Problem making a Data Base Backup with the sp_BackupDataBase procedure

Tags: advantage-database-server

hope you all are O.k!

I have this problem with the sp_BackupDateBase procedure.

According with the Advantage documentation, I can make a Backup of my Data base,
passing a UNC destination path as a parameter.
Supposing that my local machine has the IP Address 201.0.0.87, my procedure looks like this

EXECUTE PROCEDURE sp_BackupDatabase(‘\201.0.0.87\Shared\Backup’,NULL);

When I execute it, everything is just fine, and the Backup is made succesfully.

The question is: Can I make a backup, passing the IP Addres of another machine? Is this possible?

If the answer was yes, then here's my real problem.

If I pass the IP of another machine, which has granted to every user all the write-read rights, when I execute
the procedure, I get the following error message:

poQuery: Error 7200: AQE Error: State = HY000; NativeError = 7040; [Anywhere Solutions][Advantage SQL][ASA] File creation error:
Verify the specified path and file name is correct and that no other users have the file open

What should I do to make the procedure works under this conditions?

It's important to mention that both machines are in the same Work Group.

Really hope that you can help me, and if there's a doubt, feel free to ask me anything that can make this even clearer.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I'm going to assume the single backslash at the beginning of your address is a typo here, not in your code.

Answer (score 2):

> The question is: Can I make a backup,
>   passing the IP Addres of another
>   machine? Is this possible?

If I understand your question, the answer is no.  [sp_BackupDatabase](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/index.html?master_sp_backupdatabase.htm) will not back up files to a remote machine in the sense that it will connect to that machine and "send" the backup image to it (e.g., via TCP/IP). Rather, it copies table contents to a the given path using the target location as a file path.

However, if the Advantage Database Server service has access to the path as a network share, then it will make the backup on the remote machine.  [The online backup overview](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/webhelp/Advantage10.1/master_online_backup.htm) discusses this idea.

You will likely need to make sure the Advantage service can access network shares.  [This KB item](http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?Key=17&RefNo=090709-2193) discusses it.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Thanks to that, I had to change the way I was making my Backups. Now, I can make my backup of the entire database, but only the tables linked to the Data Dictionary.
I was able to do this by connecting to the machine with Advantage and executing the sp_BackupDataBase procedure. Now, my problem is with the Free Tables. When I execute the sp_BackupFreeTables procedure from my local machine (while connected to that with Advantage), I get this error message:
Error 5024: Advantage does not have a connection open with the specified handle. Connection not to same server. Any ideas?

Comment: @Alex:  It sounds like the first parameter to sp_BackupFreeTables is incorrect.  Advantage attempts to make a database connection to the path that is specified in the first parameter.  If, for example, you specified the target path as the first parameter, it would result in the 5024 error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll do what you told me!